# Is it possible to create bar chart graph in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

Surfing net did not help to figure out if xamarin supports charts.

Could someone kindly help on this?

Comment: I'm interested too. Cross platform could be very great :-) On http://components.xamarin.com/ I saw pixtate but I just bant 3 or 4 bar im my app's (Android, IOS and WPhone) or barchart but not for wphone :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xamarin MonoTouch framework doesn't include charts, but check out my port of the OxyPlot library:

https://github.com/Emasoft/OxyPlot.2DGraphLib.MonoTouch

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't support charts? Charts are "just" a visual element which don't need much support. However Xamarin.iOS / MonoTouch do not have built in Chart controls.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to buy something professional, you can check out these controls: http://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobicharts/ or http://www.steema.com/tags/monotouch/. Basically just google it "Monotouch charts/graphs".

**EDIT**
You should also check out https://components.xamarin.com/. The controls that I mentioned above, I think, are in the component store and there are also other ones that may be free. Also, if you go the component store route, adding them to your project should be a breeze since Xamarin Studio (and Visual Studio) supports/does this for you.

or try
http://infragistics.com/nuclios

Answer (score 0):

Oxyplot charting supports Xamarin under MIT licencing. Just tested it.
It's impressive, although the interaction with the chart view doesn't seem to be there right now.

http://www.oxyplot.org/

http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/OxyPlot.XamarinIOS/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Syncfusion. There are Xamarin plugin with lots of charts easy to use and many other component to try. Rich and really good!
There is a community license so you can use it for free.
https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/chart

Answer (score 0):

For bar graphs, [SciChart](https://www.scichart.com) has a Stacked Bar / Stacked Column chart demo below

- [Xamarin Stacked Bar Chart](https://www.scichart.com/example/xamarin-stacked-bar-chart-example/) (horizontal)
- [Stacked Column](https://www.scichart.com/example/xamarin-stacked-column-chart-example/) (Vertical)
- [Bar/Column chart](https://www.scichart.com/example/xamarin-chart-stacked-grouped-column-chart-side-by-side-example/) (vertical)

[image: Xamarin Column Chart]

*Disclosure, I am the tech lead of the SciChart Xamarin project*